# Changing order of integration over a general region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and a region $R$ described by $R=\{(x,y) : a\leq x\leq b , \text{ and } g_1(x)\leq b\leq g_2(x)\},$ the volume of $f$ over the region $R$ is $$\int_a^b\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)}f(x,y)dydx.$$

Why can't we just switch order of integration to say this is equal to $$\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)}\int_a^bf(x,y)dxdy?$$

I know that if we can describe $R$ as $\{h_1(x)\leq x\leq b , c\leq y\leq b\}$ then the integral is $\int_c^d\int_{h_1(x)}^{h_2(x)}f(x,y)dxdy,$ but what's wrong with just straight up switching the order of integration like we do over rectangles?

Comment: Many reasons. If you first integrate wrt $x$, how can the next iterated integral have bounds that depend on $x$? Which $x$ do you pick? Moreover, the answer will depend on $x$. Again, which $x$? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry I don't quite follow, what's the difference between the first integral having bounds of $x$ versus the second? We just treat $x$ like a constant when we integrate with respect to $y$, whether it's on the outside or inside.

Comment: Just try it an see what happens! Take a very simple example: a triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$. Let $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < x$.  Then $\int_0^1 \int_0^x dy \, dx = \frac{1}{2}$ (the area of the triangle). What would happen if you try to do $\int_0^x \int_0^1 dx \, dy$? The inner integral, $\int_0^1 dx$ gives you $1$, but then what is left is $\int_0^x dy$. It would seem the "answer" is $x$, but this doesn't make sense (this is what zugzug meant in the comments above).